# PlaceholderProperty binding

Tags: mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I have a view, with two basic fields, named ID and Name, The TextProperty of these fields are bound to my ViewModel, using `StudentID.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("StudentID"));`

Student ID is an `int`. In the view I have made placeholders for these fields. However, for `int` fields they are default set to 0. So, when the page loads, the placeholder of `int` field is always 0.

How can I bind the `PlaceholderProperty` of the `int` field? I am using MVVMCross and Xamarin.Forms.

Note : I am using C# and not XAML code for my View definition.

Comment: Isnt there an `Entry.PlaceholderProperty` property?

Comment: Yes there is one, but i am not sure what i have done is correct or not,
View:
StudentID.SetBinding(Entry.PlaceholderProperty, new Binding("StudentIDPlaceHolder"));


ViewModel:
private string _SIDPH;
        public string StudentIDPlaceHolder 
        {
            get { return _SIDPH; }

            set { _SIDPH = "ID"; } 
        }

this didn't help.

Comment: So just to understand, you would like the placeholder to display some text?  ie.. `Enter number`?

Comment: Exactly !! but since the TextProperty is been binded i get a '0' displayed on my Entry field.

Comment: Hmm, you might want to make your id a nullable int, that way the default is null. Or possibly create a converter, that checks if the value is 0, then return null instead.

Comment: @Johan,

true, but somewhere i read that the limitaion of Xamarin forms is that, i cant use nullable int.

Answer (score 0):

Change your binding to

```
StudentID.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding(path: "StudentID", converter: new IntToStringConverter()));
```

and create a converter

```
public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((int)value) == 0) ? null : ((int)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int retVal;
        if(!(Int.TryParse((string)value, retVal)) retVal = 0;
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

This way if your int is 0, the value will be passed as null, but any other values will be passed correctly. When the text value of an entry is null the placeholder text is shown, so you can just do `StudentID.Placeholder = "Enter student ID";` and that will be displayed until a number is entered. The string validation in the converter is very basic and can definitely be improved.

Comment: this code has 2 problems: 

1. tryparse needs out key word
2. Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int'


not sure how to get rid of them.